# How do I solve a 500 internal server error on a cgi file trying to run python

Tags: python, html, flask, cgi, cgi-bin

I want to run a python script on a website which is hosted by Strato (.nl), and I'm trying to do this with a CGI file.
[My code: cgi file, python file and a dependencies file to add something to the PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FwK2.png)

[This is what the folders look like in the server from the website I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5rzd.png). I also changed all the permissions to 755

I followed this German guy's explanation step-by-step: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCCSGR9CVk8. Everything went well except for the very final step, where he loads the page in his browser and gets a "Hello, World!" while I get a 500 Internal server error. The thing is, I have no idea at all what caused this error. The guy from the video and I have the same hosting and the video is not even a year old so it's not like a lot could have changed. I guess the first step to finding a solution would be figuring out what exactly causes this error, but it doesn't give any more information than the generic "500 internal server error". Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, apperently my code was fine but the text editor I used added the wrong line endings. If you have this same problem, try changing the line endings in all your files from windows to unix.